# Error on upgrade of database

Tags: database, upgrade

I manually upgraded a Joomla `3.3` to `3.4.8`, but `Extensions > Manage >  Database` showed:

> The Joomla! Core database tables have not been converted yet to UTF-8
>   Multibyte (utf8mb4).

I clicked `Fix`, and then received the error

```
Error on rename of '.\hydair3\#sql-32d4_c.frm' to '.\hydair3\#__overrider.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) SQL=ALTER TABLE `#__overrider` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Error on rename of '.\hydair3\#sql-32d4_c.frm' to '.\hydair3\#__postinstall_messages.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) SQL=ALTER TABLE `#__postinstall_messages` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Duplicate key name 'idx_alias' SQL=ALTER TABLE `#__categories` ADD KEY `idx_alias` (`alias`(100));
```

The database user has full permissions to the database.

Help appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited `configuration.php` and replaced the db user with the local MySQL `root` user, and the errors no longer occurred.

This must mean the local MySQL user has rights issues to the local MySQL database.